# How to override default timestamp format while reading csv in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have the following data in a CSV format,

```
ID|TIMESTAMP_COL
1|03-02-2003 08:37:55.671 PM
2|2003-02-03 08:37:55.671 AM
```

and my code for reading the above CSV is,

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sch = StructType([StructField("ID",StringType(),False),StructField("TIMESTAMP_COL",StringType(),True)])

df = spark.read \
            .format("csv") \
            .option("encoding", "utf-8") \
            .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE") \
            .option("header", "true") \
            .option("dateFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy") \
            .option("timestampFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS a") \
            .option("delimiter", "|") \
            .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record") \
            .schema(sch) \
            .load("data.csv")
```

So, according to the given timestamp format, I should get the record with id '2' rejected as it has a different format but it gets parsed but the value is different.

The output I am getting is,

```
df.show(truncate=False)

+-------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|           ID|          TIMESTAMP_COL|    _corrupt_record|
+-------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|            1|2003-02-03 08:37:55.671|               null|
|            2|0008-07-26 08:37:55.671|               null|
+-------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it helps but here is what i found:

1. In your schema second field is declared as StringType, shouldnt it be TimestampType()?

I was able to reproduce your results with spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY") i did also tests with other possible options for this parameter

```
 object LegacyBehaviorPolicy extends Enumeration {
    val EXCEPTION, LEGACY, CORRECTED = Value
  }
```

and here is doc for this parameter:

```
 .doc("When LEGACY, java.text.SimpleDateFormat is used for formatting and parsing " +
      "dates/timestamps in a locale-sensitive manner, which is the approach before Spark 3.0. " +
      "When set to CORRECTED, classes from java.time.* packages are used for the same purpose. " +
      "The default value is EXCEPTION, RuntimeException is thrown when we will get different " +
      "results.")
```

So with LEGACY i am getting same results as you

With EXCEPTION Spark is throwing exception

```
 org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: [INCONSISTENT_BEHAVIOR_CROSS_VERSION.PARSE_DATETIME_BY_NEW_PARSER] You may get a different result due to the upgrading to Spark >= 3.0:
```

With CORRECTED Spark is returning nulls for both records

It is however parsing correctly record with id 1 when i change pattern to hh instead of HH

so with something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","CORRECTED")

sch = StructType([StructField("ID",StringType(),False),StructField("TIMESTAMP_COL",TimestampType(),True), StructField("_corrupt_record", StringType(),True)])

df = spark.read \
            .format("csv") \
            .option("encoding", "utf-8") \
            .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE") \
            .option("header", "true") \
            .option("dateFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy") \
            .option("timestampFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS a") \
            .option("delimiter", "|") \
            .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record") \
            .schema(sch) \
            .load("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/stack.csv") \
        
df.show(truncate = False)
```

I am able to get this on output:

```
+---+-----------------------+----------------------------+
|ID |TIMESTAMP_COL          |_corrupt_record             |
+---+-----------------------+----------------------------+
|1  |2003-02-03 20:37:55.671|null                        |
|2  |null                   |2|2003-02-03 08:37:55.671 AM|
+---+-----------------------+----------------------------+
```

I am getting null here because thats how Spark parser is working, when pattern is incorrect its assigning null and your value is not going to be moved to corrupted_records i think so if you want to remove not matching timestamps you may filter nulls

Edit: As mentioned in comment i was missing this column in schema, its added now and you can get corrupted_value if you need it

Comment: Just to complete this great answer by a tiny bit: if you add a `StructField("_corrupt_record", StringType(),True)` to your schema, you'll get the corrupt records in your schema and the third column that contains the wrongly formatted strings!

Comment: This works, thank you for such a detailed answer